# Failed to load webpack config. Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module is not supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, tailwind-css

Hey I have build a webpack project. I am trying to setup tailwindcss but because of dependancy of some node module I am getting this error when creating a dev build.

Error:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/rishavbharti/Desktop/test/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/rishavbharti/Desktop/test/node_modules/string-width/index.js from /Users/rishavbharti/Desktop/test/node_modules/cliui/build/index.cjs not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/rishavbharti/Desktop/test/node_modules/cliui/build/index.cjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rishavbharti/Desktop/fridayy-embed/node_modules/cliui/build/index.cjs:291:21) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
/* global __dirname, require, module*/

const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const env = require("yargs").argv.env; // use --env with webpack 2
const pkg = require("./package.json");

let libraryName = "test";

let outputFile, mode;

if (env === "build") {
  mode = "production";
  outputFile = libraryName + ".min.js";
} else {
  mode = "development";
  outputFile = libraryName + ".js";
}

const config = {
  mode: mode,
  entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public/lib",
    filename: outputFile,
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        // exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve("./node_modules"), path.resolve("./src")],
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-add-module-exports"]
}
```

The error suggests to edit node module file but I dont want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets do it in parts:

In the webpack.config.js, under the exclude property in the rule for JS/JSX files, you should try replace module-to-transpile and another-module with the actual names of the modules from node_modules. So you should identify which modules are causing the issue.

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const env = require("yargs").argv.env;

//.... your code 

const config = {
  mode: mode,
  entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public/lib",
    filename: outputFile,
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(module-to-transpile|another-module)\/).*/, // Replace with actual modules names
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve("./node_modules"), path.resolve("./src")],
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
};
```

In your .babelrc file, you are using Babel to convert ES6 modules into a simpler format ---> CommonJS.
Ensure that all Babel dependencies (@babel/preset-env, @babel/preset-react, @babel/plugin-transform-runtime, etc.) are installed in your project.

```
.babelrc :
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",  // Ensures compatibility with the environment
    "@babel/preset-react" // If you're using React
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" // Helps to reuse Babel's injected helper code to save on codesize
  ]
}
```